# Find duplicate entries with location in excel

Tags: excel, find, duplicates, row

My excel contains students data. I want to stop duplicate entries but don't know how. Please help! In my excel sheet column B has student's name, C Father's name, D Mother's name and E date of birth. I want, if data already filled in row 15 (say) and I repeat in row 210 (say) then it will warn and also show  the previous location i.e. row 15. For this condition Student's name, father's name, date of birth etc must be same.

Comment: What you are asking, without VBA, is doable but quite complex, and you should first try by yourself and, if no success, post as part of your question what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy using just formulas and two extra columns.

Add a column which concatenates the data columns:

`=A2&B2&C2&D2`

Or slightly more robustly, adding a delimiter character:

`=A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2&"|"&D2`

Then, add a column which `countif`s the previous column to see if the value is included more than once.

`=Countif( E:E, E2 )`

Or to be slightly fancier and avoid false positives on blank rows,

`=If( A2<>"", CountIf( E:E, E2 ))`

You can then use that column to apply conditional formatting on that row.

[image]

Comment: But if I was you, I'd key only on StudentName and StudentDoB. Every time someone records a name, there's a chance they'll record a different version e.g. Bill/William, and the fewer names you key from the lower the chance of an false negative.